# postgresql loop through dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

table tableName with data like:

| from | to | id | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00 | 2021-01-01 14:30 | 1 | 20 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00 | 2021-01-10 00:00 | 15 | 36 |

then i get some set of dates

```
select * 
from pg_catalog.generate_series('2021-01-01 00:00'::timestamp, '2021-01-01 14:30', '1 hour')
```

and get set of intervals. The first entry in that set is `2021-01-01 00:00:00.000`, the second is `2021-01-01 01:00:00.000` I need to check if any data from my table has has from or to date within that interval (first and second). If it is within the range than count duration which that id has in that interval. For example for the first one it should count and get result like 1hour (from 00:00 to 01:00). How to write such query?

Comment: Can you add database schema, sample datas and expected result ?

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: Please add the expected results you expect from given data and the combination Please included the expected results of your test data with the set of dates. A particular situation being what do you want when the FROM, TO combination overlap 2 or more set of intervals. Example (from, to) = (2021-01-01 00:30, 2021-01-01 02:15) and intervals "2021-01-01 00:00,2021-01-01 01:00", "2021-01-01 01:00, 2021-01-01 01:30", "2021-01-01 01:30, 2021-01-01 02:00", "20210-01-01 02:00 - 2021-01-01 02:30". Are the intervals Open or Closed for both start and end. –

Answer (score 3):

(Would be mess as a comment)

You can get times like this but I really didn't understand what you need as output (also you should decide if you want the boundaries inclusive or exclusive, I wrote as exclusive):

```
with times as (
select t.sh, t.sh + interval '1 hour' as eh
from pg_catalog.generate_series(
    '2021-01-01 00:00'::timestamp, 
    '2021-01-01 14:30', '1 hour') t(sh)
)
select *
from myTable mt 
inner join times t on mt."from" < t.eh and mt."to" > t.sh;
```

Comment: You are correct, thanks for pointing it out. Comment moved to question not your answer.